# Accessing external server site in case user is not on VPN in Asp.Net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, network-programming, window

I have a situation. Our company has two server one is accessed from VPN like intranet etc. and another is an external server for the external users i.e. non-employee. Now what I want to do is I need to create one page in asp.net to capture some information. So what it should do is if the user is on VPN then he should be redirected to our internal server and if the user is not on VPN it should be redirected to the external server.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: I imagine you can do it based on IP address.

Comment: I would add some very simple API to your VPN accessible server, which you can call to prove you are on VPN (e.g. `https://vpn-server/api/is_vpn` which responds like `true` ). Then you might be able to redirect based on API result - `true` for VPN environment, `Error 404 Not Found` for non-VPN environments.